# How to return from string to JSON on WebScraping?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, web-scraping

I have been trying for some sort of web scraping and I cant figure out the problem I am facing right now which is pretty easy I assume.

What I wanted to do is get each of product titles from a particular website and print them in json format. Every product title comes very clear when I console but when I try for json, It shows only first element and gives an error. I believe there is some kind of asynchronous problem is exist or maybe the reason is I am forgetting for loop before printing json file and It takes first element of 'product title' and prints.

Thanks for any response.

Cheers

```
var express         = require('express'),
    app             = express(),
    request         = require('request'),
    cheerio         = require('cheerio')
    port            = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    bodyParser      = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/product", function(req, res){

        request('someWebsite', (error, response, html) => {
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                 const $ = cheerio.load(html);

                $('.product').each((i, el) => {
                    var productTitle = $(el)
                        .find('.product-name')
                        .text();

                    // console.log(productTitle);

                    res.send(
                        {
                            message:productTitle
                        }
                    );

                })
            }
        });
});

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('App is running on port' + port); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling `res.send()` inside a loop. But you can send data and closing the connection with the client (that is what actually `res.send()` is doing) only one time.

If the JSON object dimensions are acceptable, you can construct the JSON object while iterating over `.product` elements, and send it back to the client once you finished parsing.

```
request('someWebsite', (error, response, html) => {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            let obj = {} // create an empty object
            $('.product').each((i, el) => {
                var productTitle = $(el)
                    .find('.product-name')
                    .text();

                // console.log(productTitle);

                // do not call res.send() inside "each" iteration

            })

            res.send(obj) // call res.send() AFTER "each" loop. 
        }
    });
```

Comment: I were about write my answer which I have used array rather than object but object sounds better for my purpose. Thanks for your response!